# PhoneGap + Drupal + Drupal for Facebook module

Tags: facebook, drupal, cordova

I am Developing Iphone application using Phonegap and I got all the data of it from Drupal website now I need to let the user connect to the facebook to login and in the website I am using Drupal for facebook module.

Do I need to add a new facebook connect system to my app or there is a way to use the same facebook connect button in the Drupal website?